# Java options in weblogic server and servlet debugging

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

We are migrating from weblogic 8.1 to weblogic 12.1 version. Most of the java.applications are.working fine.We have one java application which refers the JAVA OPTIONS set in custom startup script.Though we have set the options , the file set on those JAVA OPTIONS doesn't seem to be picking up.Is there any way to debug this in WLS?

Comment: Under Linux, use a `ps -ef | grep weblogic` command and check that all JVM properties are set or not

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic is printing out JAVA_OPTIONS in the first lines of the .out log file when it starts up.

If it is not printed, then it is not used.

You should change the startup options of the managed server if you want to add custom JAVA OPTIONS.